# select query with an update subquery

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update a table with this query,

```
update posts (SELECT id, url from posts order by id DESC LIMIT 500) set url = replace(url, 'domain.com', 'domain.org')
```

This is a query that I have to run each week. it's important that is applies to the latest 500 entries only, not the entire table.

Of course the query above doesn't work, what is the correct syntax for a such query?

Comment: What does the `posts` table have to do with the query? It seems unused.

Comment: @ogc-nick, sorry, fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE `posts` SET `url` = replace(`url`, 'domain.com', 'domain.org') ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 500;
```

From the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html):

> If the ORDER BY clause is specified, the rows are updated in the order
>   that is specified. The LIMIT clause places a limit on the number of
>   rows that can be updated.

Also note that you don't have to select a column to order by it.